# Why java.ci.totalTime bigger then sun.rt.safepointTime (JVM PerfCounters)?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jit, jvm-hotspot

I'm using JVM's PerfCounters and don't understand why java.ci.totalTime bigger then sun.rt.safepointTime.

For example when:
I calculate total_GC_time like  this sun.gc.collector.0.time + sun.gc.collector.1.time = total_GC_time.
This total_GC_time is always  less sun.rt.safepointTime, it's OK.

But I don't understand why java.ci.totalTime bigger then sun.rt.safepointTime ?

May be java.ci.totalTime it's background operation and don't generate jvm pause(safepoint)

Then how to understand how long JIT takes in SafePoint pause ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are completely unrelated things.

`java.ci.totalTime` is the total time spent in JIT compilation. This has nothing to do with safepoints. JIT compilers work in background while application threads are running.